# Wordpress website with Woocommerce. super weird issue at checkout

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, divi

I have a really odd issue with a website of a friend.

The website is ********* (Sorted now, thank you all :)

**Issue / Steps to replicate the issue**

When an item is put in the cart and then you head directly to checkout.
Then Select required shipping option – values don’t change. **

**Caveat
If you are using a high resolution monitor it will work (for example 4k)
When using 1080p monitor its more likely to fail.
In this case, the calculation step performed is not being triggered.
If (in the case of a 1080p resolution screen) you zoom the page out so the whole page can be seen, the shipping works fine.

I'm lost, when I use Chrome and inspect the page (and head under network) I can see a process trigger when the page is scrolled down to the bottom and am assuming that this is the triggering process ?

Any smart people out there is any ideas i can try ?
I appreciate the help :)

Tried disabling all cache plugins, checked all settings.
All plugins/themes up to date.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout contains duplicate of Divi column (".et_pb_column_1_tb_body"), just like the DevTools console warns about. The duplication happens when column becomes sticky.

Try to disable stickiness of the mentioned column. If this solves your issue, try different approach for making the element sticky without duplication.